# 128 downloads limit with rtorrent and transmission-daemon

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

I was trying to download a bigger bunch (1000+) of torrents the other day.

- Transmission (with GUI) on Mac started struggling after 300+ torrents.
- Then I tried with `rtorrent` on Linux. I put all torrent files in its watch folder, but it would pick up the first 128 only.
- Then I tried `transmission-daemon` on Linux. Again, although I put all the torrent files inside its watch folder it picked & downloaded only the first 128.

I haven't seen this hard limit specified in any config options neither in `rtorrent` or `transmission-daemon`, so I assume it has to be a Linux thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the ouput of `ulimit`? Note that for `transmission` at least, there are some configurable limits that can impact the number of active torrents (and number of peers).